# FTP Not Retrieving Complete File

Tags: c#, ftp

I have the following code;

```
/// <summary>
///   Gets a file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filename"> The filename to get. </param>
/// <returns> A list, containing each line of the file </returns>
public IEnumerable<string> GetFileLines(string filename)
{
  var list = new List<string>();

  var uri = BuildUri(filename);

  var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.Uri);
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

  using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  {
    using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
      Thread.Sleep(10000);
      if (stream != null)
      {
        using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
          // If we still have characters to process
          while (responseStream.Peek() >= 0)
          {
            var line = responseStream.ReadLine();
            list.Add(line);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return list;
}
```

However it is not pulling the whole file from the FTP- it seems to cut off before the end of the file has finished downloading.

Is there anything I can add to extend the time it allows to retrieve the data?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Is there any error whilst reading?  Have you tried using the FTP address in a web browser to manually get the file and checked that is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `responseStream.Peek`, use below code (You can also remove `Thread.Sleep` safely)

```
string line;
while((line = responseStream.ReadLine())!=null)
{

    list.Add(line);
}
```